# Which grammar rule allows us to modify a clause with an -ing?

Tags: modifiers

In the sentence below, what function does "including" serve? What do I need to learn to be able to create these sentences on my own?

> Most jobs, however, require at least a bachelor’s degree; majors of
>   transportation planners are varied, **including** fields such as
>   urban studies, civil engineering, geography, or transportation and
>   logistics management.

Answer (score 3):

*Including* here is a present participle (or "gerund-participle", if you follow Huddleston & Pullum). There are a number of ways of parsing its use here:

1. as the head of an adjectival participle phrase modifying *majors of transportation planners* or glossing *varied*
2. as the head of a supplemental gerund-participle clause taking *majors of transportation planners* as its inferred subject
3. as the preposition heading a preposition phrase glossing *varied*

I prefer 2.: I take this to be a distinct predication equivalent to *They* (the majors) *include fields such as ...* with its verb recast as a non-finite *-ing* form in order to subordinate it to the main clause.

Answer (score 0):

> *Most jobs, however, require at least a bachelor’s degree; majors of
>   transportation planners are varied, **including fields such as urban
>   studies, civil engineering, geography, or transportation and** logistics
>   management.*

"Including" is best analysed as a preposition whose function is **head** of the  PP, in bold. Since there is no understood subject it makes no sense to analyse it as a verb, although it is derived by conversion from the gerund-participle form of the verb "include".

A case could be made for the PP being a supplementary adjunct, since it's set apart from the rest of the clause by a comma (and a slight pause in speech). It doesn’t modify anything, but serves as a separate unit of information, additional to the main part of the clause.